# VBA: Getting error method range of object _worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I keep getting error as mentioned in the title when executing the below code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 2
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Email" Then
        Sheets("Lists").Range("Z2:Z31").Cells.Value = ""
        For i = 2 To 190
            If Sheets("Lists").Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(2, 2).Value Then
                Sheets("Lists").Cells(j, 26).Value = Sheets("Lists").Cells(i, 6).Value
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
        Range("C12:O12").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & Range("B1").Value, xlAnd, "<=" & Range("C1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is automatically executed when any change happens in the worksheet by adding this class event.

```
Public WithEvents appevent As Application
Private Sub appevent_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
    Call test
End Sub
```

And using the `Workbook_Open` method in the `ThisWorkbook` tab in VBA to add the event automatically when the worksheet open as the below.

```
Dim myobject As New Class1
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set myobject.appevent = Application
End Sub
```

Although when executed normally through debugger by just pressing F5 the code executes flawlessly.

What I'm trying to do is after the user selects an option from a data validated cell, the sheet auto updates the content viewed in that sheet and also sets some other cells in the "Lists" sheet to different values from the original ones.

So far, the code executes flawlessly when run through debugger by pressing F5, so I'm out of ideas why such an error occurs. My guess is that VBA doesn't allow changing cell values programmatically unless the sheet is selected, so how can I do that if the sheet isn't selected.

If you can please kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: While I did workaround it by selecting the sheet with `Sheets("Lists").Select` and continuing the code execution, however if there is an answer I'd be interested.

Comment: Have you ever looked into Excel's FILTER function?  It looks like you're trying to produce a filtered list of data based on a Validated selection. FILTER will do that for you with no code needed (unless you need the data as values and then you just have to write the formula and convert it to Values).

Comment: @FrankBall interesting answer, let me get back to that after couple of hours of testing. Also if you can please attach an example as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Range(...) and Cells(...) without specifying the Sheet. It is not good practice to use .Select to set a reference object, but prefer to set the object explicitly.

```
Sub test()
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 2
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Email" Then
        With Worksheets("Lists")
         .Range("Z2:Z31").value = ""
         For i = 2 To 190
 'IN NEXT LINE the Cells(2,2).Value comes form ActiveSheet... 
 'is this you need or is a mistake? check it.
             If .Cells(i, 8).value = Cells(2, 2).value Then
                 .Cells(j, 26).value = .Cells(i, 6).value
                 j = j + 1
             End If
         Next
  'I PUT A DOT in Ranges... Is this you need Or have to refer the ActiveSheet?
         .Range("C12:O12").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & .Range("B1").value, xlAnd, "<=" & .Range("C1").value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

In any case all Range(...) and Cells(...) need a parent, and: if the code lives in a sheet, the parent is the sheet ELSE you have to define it somehow. You do it with Sheet("...").Select. So the Cells(2, 2).value and  Range("C12:O12").AutoFilter ..Range("B1").value.. Range("C1").value... comes from sheet "Lists".

```
'This code in Email sheet module. Also move the Sub test() here.
'You don't need a Class module...
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Call test
End Sub


Private Sub test()
   '.......
   '.......
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Still getting the same error when using this code
`Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`
I only changed the last line by removing the dots before the Range as I need it to refer to the active sheet.

Comment: Even when run from the debugger. Although after I run it from the debugger once, it runs with no problems after that whether from the debugger or by the event. Maybe an issue with my excel at this point?

Comment: You dont want the Activesheet. The check: If ActiveSheet.Name = "Email"  ... means that this code executed only in  Worksheets("Email"). So change the Range to: Worksheets("Email").Range(....)

Comment: While what you say is true, but keep in mind this is a code auto executed when the event `SheetChange` happens. I don't want the code to be executed on every change in the workbook but only changes in the "Email" sheet. Also tried that and didn't work either, at this point I'll just use the workaround.

Comment: Since you want test() to run only when you have changes in the "Email" sheet, why not run it through the Worksheet_Change of the Email sheet? (so there is no need to check which is active Sheet)

Comment: And how do I do that? Would adding the third code block to "Email" sheet instead of a class do the trick? Would it still run the event when the workbook opens?